# Suppose that $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is an onto function and $C$ and $D$ are subsets of $Y$ such that $f^{-1}(C)= f^{-1}(D)$. Then $ C = D$.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Suppose that $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is an onto function and $C$ and $D$ are subsets of $Y$ such that $f^{-1}(C)= f^{-1}(D)$. Then $ C = D$.

I think this statement is false and I am trying to come up with a counterexample.

I am wanting to use the function $f: R \rightarrow R$ be the function defined by $y=x^2$ but I am not sure how to come up with sets of Y, and subsets C and D.

Comment: The problem with your example is that the f you chose is not onto.

Comment: @JohnBrevik I don't think the surjectivity of $f$ really has an effect on the problem from an intuitive standpoint - doesn't the surjectivity just make it so that we can't have $C$ be identical to the set of $D$ except with some added element $y$ which has no $x$ with $f(x) = y$?

Comment: @Soke Sorry, I can't make out what you mean by "no effect." Your analysis is correct, but that makes subjectivity essential.

Comment: @JohnBrevik When you said "the problem with your example" I thought you meant the reason why OP was having trouble to come up with subset C and D is because f was not onto, and I was saying that even though f is not subjective, you can still understand the problem intuitively and come up with some examples (although they'd be ultimately wrong).

Answer (score 1):

The statement is true, because under the given assumptions, $f(f^{-1}(A)) = A$ for all $A \subseteq Y$. Indeed, let $A \subseteq Y$. If $y \in A$, then $y = f(x)$ for some $x \in X$ (since $f$ is onto), which implies $x \in f^{-1}(A)$ and hence $y \in f(f^{-1}(A))$. Conversely, if $y \in f(f^{-1}(A))$, then $y = f(z)$ for some $z \in f^{-1}(A)$. So $f(z) \in A$, i.e., $y \in A$. Therefore $y \in A$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $c\in C$ and $c\notin D$.

Since $f$ is onto the set $f^{-1}(\{c\})\subset f^{-1}(C)$ is not empty and its elements do not belong to $f^{-1}(D)$ so that $f^{-1}(C)\neq f^{-1}(D)$.

Of course this also works if $d\notin D$ and $d\in D$ and proved is now $C\neq D\implies f^{-1}(C)\neq f^{-1}(D)$. So the statement is true.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to add yet another answer, but for a learner I think that a straightforward approach is best. How do you prove two sets equal? Prove that each is contained in the other. So let $y\in C$. Since $f$ is onto, there exists $x\in X$ such that $f(x)=y.$ Now $x\in f^{-1}(C)$. But then $x\in f^{-1}(D)$, so $f(x)\in D$. Maybe I'll let the OP finish...